# Suds Type not Found

Tags: python, suds

I am trying to execute a soap service with suds. The signature from server for the parameter looks like this (taken from `print(client)`)

```
xs:anyType orderBy
```

My suds client throws the following exception

```
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'orderBy'
```

In my code i pass the following array as argument

```
['DESC']
```

In PHP it works like this

```
$client->serviceFunctionName([...], array( 'eventdate' => 'DESC' ))
```

In the original WSDL-XML from Server the Parameter looks like this

```
<wsdl:part name="orderBy" type="xs:anyType"/>
```

How can i correctly accomplish this in python suds?

**UPDATE**

Tried the following, which gets rejected by the server

```
dict(eventdate='DESC')
```

Error message from Server

```
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Invalid parameter type: param=sort expected=Array got=object'
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually not worth fighting for. Most old web apis delivers some PHP code that just works. If you have it use it to generate template that later on you may use with non SOAP requests lib that you are familiar with:

```
<?php 
  // Setting up SOAP request here like in api documentation

  echo "REQUEST BODY:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
  echo "REQUEST HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "\n";
```

Headers will usually contain content type, basic authorisation token, and endpoint for making requests. Body can be used to create template that may be parameterise and used to request with python or any other stack.

Comment: This is actually finally the way that i solved it as well.